# SailsJS MongoDB store and access Array of Object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I'm trying to make a real-time vote application using SailsJS, and am currently having troubles with MongoDB. I am completely new to this, and have been just using SailsJS mimic easy calls to access MongoDB.

```
    module.exports = {

      attributes: {
        selectOptions:{
         type: 'Object'
           },
         question:{
          type:'string',
            required: true
         },
          password:{
           type:'string',
          required: true
        }
      }
  };
```

The above code is for the model that I have, and I am the selectOptions should have an array of objects, like [{id: 1,result: 0},{id:2,result 0},...] and would like to know how to do this, as I cannot seem to find any documentation about the array of objects. Only thing I found was something about collection, or making another model and link that to the original model, but when i tried it, sails gave me some foreign key error that I have never faced before. I really really appreciate your time, and look forward for the response.

P.S - I tried making the array into either JSON or Object or nothing(Like not put any type under selectOptions) and made change to the model as well to see if it works, but both JSON and Object didn't work, but selectOptions did. However, I think it was returning a string, as it the length was longer than what the array was supposed to be.

Comment: I have some thoughts on this, but it would help if you gave a bit more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually, I figured out that mongodb from sailsjs would make users to save an array of object without any problem, but it wasn't apparently. I figured another long way of doing this by just converting things into string to json, back and forth to accomplish this.